# How can I set Kubernetes to use an unsigned Enterprise Root CA when pulling down pods

Tags: kubernetes

I get this error when pulling down my pods:

```
Failed to pull image "jenkins:2.60.3": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error while 
pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/jenkins/images: 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I work at a corporation and the corp has an unsigned Enterprise Root Cert. I have it saved as `cert.pem`.

Can I start `minikube` and have it use the certificate so I can download from `https` sources. If not, can I enable insecure `http` sources?

I am running Windows 7.

Comment: In your error message, docker is attempting to pull from `index.docker.io`. Are you actually internally spoofing the docker registry?

Comment: I missed the `minikube` part of your question.  In response to your comment on my answer, are you sure you can't simply specify `--insecure-registry` multiple times on the `minikube` command line?

Comment: It didn't seem to work for the docker repo that has Jenkins